# Whats going on with my Atom?

Tags: editor, atom-editor, unfold

If I use **unFold** with shortkey on last line, it's ok.

But that happens in other lines:
[image: But that happens in other lines]

When the focus is on the last line, everything comes back to normal.

Comment: looks like one or more plugins are not working well together

Comment: how I can find that event?

Comment: https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging

Comment: What packages are you using?